# After navigate to another page using routerlink in Angular2 URL change but page is not refreshing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I created this project by using Angular-Cli webpack. And I build the project and hosted in AWS with IIS

Here is the github url : https://github.com/igkmahesh/InihilPhotography

Here is the website URL : [http://www.inihilphotography.com.au](http://www.inihilphotography.com.au/home)

My Problem is. When i click on any of the Navigation link(About/Portfolio/Contact/....) which is in left side, it change the URL, but page is not loading.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 1):

All the content is there, you are just seeing right through it to the background :)

You have a "opacity: 0;" in your CSS class right-content.

Comment: When I remove the "opacity: 0" from the right content, i can see the page, but it is not properly loaded. I have to manually refresh to view it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution. The reason for not showing the page after navigate is, I have separate javascript file (custom.script.js) which is doing some modification to DOM after load the page. After navigate to another page by using angular router, those codes are not getting executed.

This is what i did to solve that issue.

1. Declare `jQuery : declare var jQuery:any;`
2. Get the custom.script.js file inside the OnInit method : `jQuery.getScript("../../assets/JS/custom.script.js");`

.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery:any;
@Component({
   selector: 'app-about',
   templateUrl: './about.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor() { }
   ngOnInit() {
      jQuery.getScript("../../assets/JS/custom.script.js");
   }
}
```